# Alternative for event machines to process pushTopics?

Tags: rest-api, streaming-api, ruby, ruby-on-rails, pushtopic

We have a Ruby app which has a continuously running Rake task which listens for Salesforce pushTopics using the gem Restforce (and Faye). The Restforce gem is compatible with an older version of Faye (from 2013) and is sometimes unstable. Are there any other alternatives that could be used instead of an event machine to receive data in our app from Salesforce? Maybe using Triggers?